# I want to count number of times ID's are present in Json Response

Tags: javascript, postman

```
{
    "page": 2,
    "per_page": 6,
    "total": 12,
    "total_pages": 2,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 7,
            "email": "michael.lawson@reqres.in",
            "first_name": "Michael",
            "last_name": "Lawson",
            "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/follettkyle/128.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "email": "lindsay.ferguson@reqres.in",
            "first_name": "Lindsay",
            "last_name": "Ferguson",
            "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/araa3185/128.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 9,
            "email": "tobias.funke@reqres.in",
            "first_name": "Tobias",
            "last_name": "Funke",
            "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/vivekprvr/128.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "email": "byron.fields@reqres.in",
            "first_name": "Byron",
            "last_name": "Fields",
            "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/russoedu/128.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 11,
            "email": "george.edwards@reqres.in",
            "first_name": "George",
            "last_name": "Edwards",
            "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/mrmoiree/128.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 12,
            "email": "rachel.howell@reqres.in",
            "first_name": "Rachel",
            "last_name": "Howell",
            "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/hebertialmeida/128.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

above is the json response. It has field names"id, email, first_name, last_name and avatar". I need to validate the count of each of these field. Expected output is :id-6 , first-name-6, email-6, last_name-6 , avatar-6.And I do not want to hard code, these fields are present in one of the csv file.  Means I do not want to hard code field name,         I want to parametrize so that it reads data from csv file.      So that even if  I have to get the count of 100 fields, the code should work. Please let me know if any other details required

Comment: use object.data.length

Comment: What is your expected output? What exactly are you trying to count?

Comment: I am assuming "per_page" gives you the count of data in the response

Comment: @VaibhavSingh don't think so. Usually when paging `per_page` means the *maximum* you can have on each page. So you can have `per_page = 10` but only show 4 items, for example, either because there are 4 in total, or there might be 14 in total and you're on page 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply count it this way

```
console.log(value.data.length)
```

unless if there is any chance that there would have been no id field then u can do this

```
var count = 0;
for (let i =0; i < value.data.length; i++) {
  if(value.data[i].id != undefined) count++
}

console.log(count)
```

Comment: This works but i need to read fieldnames from data sheet.

Comment: u mean `email`, `first_name` ?
u can read them by same way `value.data[i].ur_field_name`
and please accept the answer if its work